# directus with the serverless rds is not scaling down

Tags: amazon-rds, directus

We have setup the directus on fargate and chose the AWS serverless RDS as database

When we are not using directus then also the serverless rds is not scaling down to 0.

Does any one faced this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your setup? I am also facing this issue